# How to add custom Drawable to array and then RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add in a custom drawable (code below) into a recycler view. It works with images from the mipmap folder, but the custom drawable doesn't show up at all. Anyone know why? No errors, just the gridview doesn't appear.

Main Activity:

final int[] imageArray = new int[9];

```
        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            imageArray[i] = R.drawable.image_background_base; //<-- Not effective here

        }

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            int image = imageArray[i];
            arrayList.add(new animal_item(image));

        }

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

Custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        />
</shape>
```

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_square_shape"/>
</selector>
```

Adapter:

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ImageView imageView;

    private Uri imageUri;
    private ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ArrayList<animal_item> getDataSet() {
        return mDataSet;
    }

    public void setDataSet(ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

    }

    public AnimalsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet) {
        mDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet() {

        return mDataSet;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);

            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

            mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (listener != null) {

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        }



        public ImageView getImageView() {

            return mImageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView mImageView) {

            this.mImageView = mImageView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new View
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) mListener);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final animal_item animalItem = mDataSet.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(animalItem.getImageResource());

        imageView = holder.mImageView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Individual Item:

```
public class animal_item {

    private int imageResource;

    public animal_item(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}
```

Comment: can paste your viewholder and what are you doing inside onBind?

Comment: @tamtom Just added those in.

Comment: It also works when the drawable is a vector, but not a custom shape. Maybe I'm doing that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the layout_width and layout_height in the card view from wrap_content to the size I wanted. For some reason, the card view size determines the size of the drawable.

Updated layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="123dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```